# Android Studio Activitys - CLOSED

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to know how I could get which button was clicked from the new activity ... To explain my question please see the pictures

[image: First activity]

[image: Second activity]

I would like to know if you could apply the same code without having to create lots of activitys ... For that I thought about taking the button that you clicked and then using an if system.

Thanks (Sorry for bad english. )

Comment: if you use OnClickListener, it returns id of button which was pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to achieve is that when you click on a `Button`, it starts a new `Activity` and in the `SecondActivity` you should be able to differentiate which `Button` (of the first Actvity) started the `SecondActivity`. If it is so, then the following code will work.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String BUTTON1 = "BUTTON1";
    public static final String BUTTON2 = "BUTTON2";
    public static final String BUTTON3 = "BUTTON3";
    public static final String BUTTON4 = "BUTTON4";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button1:
                intent.putExtra("key", BUTTON1);
                break;

            case R.id.button2:
                intent.putExtra("key", BUTTON2);
                break;

            case R.id.button3:
                intent.putExtra("key", BUTTON3);
                break;

            case R.id.button4:
                intent.putExtra("key", BUTTON4);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here we have declared some constants for each button. It will help us determine from which button the `SecondActivity` was started. We will pass the constant value with the intent object to the SecondActivity and later verify it.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SecondActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        String intentKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

        Log.d(TAG, "Intent Key Message: " + intentKey);
    }
}
```

The above code of the SecondActivity shows from which button the Activity was started.

Comment: Thanks Rohit... Its what I want